# Find positive integer $x,y$ such that $7^{x}-3^{y}=4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all positive integers $x,y$ such that $7^{x}-3^{y}=4$.
It is the problem I think it can be solve using theory of congruency. But I can't process somebody please help me .
Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Let us go down the rabbit hole. Assume that there is a solution with $ x, y > 1 $, and rearrange to find

$$ 7(7^{x-1} - 1) = 3(3^{y-1} - 1) $$

Note that $ 7^{x-1} - 1 $ is divisible by $ 3 $ exactly once (since $ x > 1 $): the contradiction will arise from this.

Reducing modulo $ 7 $ we find that $ 3^{y-1} \equiv 1 $, and since the order of $ 3 $ modulo $ 7 $ is $ 6 $, we find that $ y-1 $ is divisible by $ 6 $, hence $ 3^{y-1} - 1 $ is divisible by $ 3^6 - 1 = 2^3 \times 7 \times 13 $. Now, reducing modulo $ 13 $ we find that $ 7^{x-1} \equiv 1 $, and since the order of $ 7 $ modulo $ 13 $ is $ 12 $, we find that $ x-1 $ is divisible by $ 12 $. As above, this implies that $ 7^{x-1} - 1 $ is divisible by $ 7^{12} - 1 $, which is divisible by $ 9 $. This is the desired contradiction, hence there are no solutions with $ x, y > 1 $.

For an outline of the method I used here, see [Will Jagy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/10400/will-jagy)'s answers to [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941354/elementary-solution-of-exponential-diophantine-equation-2x-3y-7/).

Comment: I did a new one yesterday by a different OP, that answer, while computationally difficult, does not have all the extra discussions of my earlier answers: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946621/finding-solutions-to-the-diophantine-equation-7a-3b100/1946810#1946810

Comment: I don't understand why $a|b$ implies that $3^{a}-1|3^{b}-1$, and I wasn't able to prove it myself.

Comment: $3^{b}-1=3^{ak}-1=(3^{a}-1)(3^{a(k-1)}+3^{a(k-2)}+...+1)$? But then doesn't the parity of $b$ matter?

Comment: @DerekLuna Why should the parity of $ b $ matter? Your identity proves the result by itself already.

Comment: I wasn't sure if everything in the middle canceled depending on the parity of $b$, but I see that it does now!

Answer (score 1):

If you take this equation mod 7 and mod 3, it becomes clearer:

$$ 7^x-3^y \equiv 4 \mod 7 \implies -3^y \equiv 4 \mod 7 $$
$$ 7^x-3^y \equiv 4 \mod 3 \implies 7^x \equiv 4 \mod 3 $$

This isolates the variables. You can either use Chinese Remainder Theorem or convert the new modular equations to normal equations to continue (as far as I can see).

Comment: #BenLaurense: Please write the full solution .

Comment: Modular arithmetic won't carry you al the way: here is an obvious solutoin $x=y=1$ and we suspect this is the only one