# Equation in integers $7^x-3^y=4$

Tags: number-theory

I don't know how to solve $7^x-3^y=4$...
I tried to see something $\pmod 7$ and $\pmod 3$ but it doesn't help at all. Can anyone give me some hints about it?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are supposed to be integers, aren't they?

Comment: yes they are... I found (1,1), but then? How to find other solutions?

Comment: See [here](http://www.m-hikari.com/ija/ija-2017/ija-5-8-2017/p/asthanaIJA5-8-2017.pdf), with $z=2$. This is a similar case. Actually, I found a solution [here](https://www.academia.edu/29934441/50_Diophantine_Equations_Problems_With_Solutions_), in "Art of Problem Solving".

Comment: According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) the only positive integers $n$ such that $n$ and $n+4$ are both perfect powers are $4,32$ and $121$ none of which are of the form you want.  I'm not sure, though, whether the results in that table reflect proven theorems or just the current state of numerical searches.

Comment: @lulu there is an elementary method when we have primes $p,q$ and $p^m - q^n = c.$  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941354/elementary-solution-of-exponential-diophantine-equation-2x-3y-7  and  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946621/finding-solutions-to-the-diophantine-equation-7a-3b100/1946810#1946810

Comment: @WillJagy  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Note: these are not quite the same $x,y$ as in the question.

brief version, we reach
$$ 7(7^x-1) = 3(3^y - 1) \; , $$
assume that $x,y > 0$ and produce a contradiction.

As $7 | (3^y - 1)$ so that $$  3^y \equiv 1 \pmod 7 \; ,  $$
we find 
$$ 6 | y  $$

Then $(3^6 - 1 )| (3^y - 1)$  while
$$ 3^6 - 1 = 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 13  $$

Next  $13 | (7^x - 1)$ so that $$ 7^x \equiv 1 \pmod {13},  $$
so $12|x $ and we use $3 | x.$ Then $7^3 - 1 | 7^x - 1,$ while
$$ 7^3 - 1 = 2 \cdot 9 \cdot 13.  $$

We have reached $$   9 | 3 (3^y-1) \; , \; $$
or
$$   3 |  (3^y-1) \; , \; $$
which contradicts $y > 0.$